# sql query for extracting values from one column where other value columns are same

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I have a data set

paper_author:

```
paper_id author_id
   1      521630
   1      972575
   1      1528710
   1      1611750
   2      1682088
   2      1589667
   2      972575 
   3      521630
   3      1589667
```

I need to get the co-author information for all the authors that is authors writing the same paper with an author and thus grouping by author

```
author_id  co_authors
 521630     972575,1528710,1611750,1589667
 972575     521630,1528710,1611750,1589667
 .......
```

In the first row for author_id=521630 authors with author_id=972575,1528710,1611750 wrote paper1 and author_id=1589667 wrote paper 3.I have written an R code

```
co_author_id<-vector()
for(i in 1:length(paper_author))
{
  author_id_data<-paper_author[i,2]
  index1<-which(paper_author$author_id %in% author_id_data
  paper_ids<-paper_author$paper_id[index1]
  index2<-which(paper_author$paper_id %in% paper_ids)
  co_authors<-paper_author$author_id[index2]
  co_author_id[i]<-paste(co_authors,collapse=" ")
 }
```

But this is very inefficient as the data size is 12 million rows and hence working with sql would be easy and nice.How could this be done with sql

Thanks

Comment: Simplest phrasing to start with is to use a correlated subquery with `string_agg`. See what the query optimizer spits out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understand you question. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5acfa/1)

```
select
    pa1.author_id,
    array_agg(pa2.author_id order by pa2.author_id) as co_author
from
    paper_author pa1
    left join
    paper_author pa2 on
        pa1.paper_id = pa2.paper_id
        and pa1.author_id != pa2.author_id
group by pa1.author_id
order by pa1.author_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The question has an R tag so I assume that R solutions are desired:

**sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
nr <- nrow(paper_author)
paper_author$seqno <- ave(1:nr, paper_author$paper_id, FUN = seq_along)


sqldf(c("create index i2 on paper_author(paper_id, seqno)",
    "select author_id, group_concat(coauthor) co_authors 
    from (
      select distinct A.author_id, C.author_id coauthor 
      from ( select * from main.paper_author where seqno = 1) A 
      left join (select * from main.paper_author where seqno > 1) C
      using (paper_id)
    ) group by author_id"))
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(paper_author, key = "paper_id")
dt[, seqno:=1:.N, by = paper_id]
m <- merge(dt[seqno == 1], dt[seqno > 1], all.x = TRUE, by = "paper_id")
unique(m[, list(author_id.x, author_id.y)])[, 
   list(co_authors = toString(author_id.y)), by = author_id.x]
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
gp <- paper_author %.% group_by(paper_id)
gp %.% 
  filter(row_number() == 1) %.%
  left_join( gp %.% filter(row_number() > 1), by = "paper_id" ) %.%
  ungroup() %.%
  select(author_id.x, author_id.y) %.%
  unique() %.%
  group_by(author_id.x) %.%
  summarise(co_authors = toString(author_id.y))
```

**base R**

```
nr <- nrow(paper_author)
seqno <- ave(1:nr, paper_author$paper_id, FUN = seq_along)
m <- merge(paper_author[seqno == 1, ], 
           paper_author[seqno > 1, ],  all.x = TRUE, by = "paper_id")
u <- unique(m[c("author_id.x", "author_id.y")])
aggregate(list(co_authors = u$author_id.y), list(author = u$author_id.x), toString)
```

Try the above with:

```
paper_author <-
structure(list(paper_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), author_id = c(521630L, 972575L, 1528710L, 1611750L, 1682088L, 
1589667L, 972575L, 521630L, 1589667L), seqno = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("paper_id", "author_id", 
"seqno"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

**REVISED**  Revised to make author unique in output.

Comment: Hi,appreciate your help, but your solution gives the co-authors for authors having the same paper_id only, but I need the co-authors for all papers combined